# How do I set the order of classes in rspec output?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

How do I set the order of classes in the output generated by:

```
rspec --format doc
```

I want the most important classes (defined by me) to come first on the documentation generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ash has provided the easy way and mentioned the major caveat of going that route.

If you want to maintain randomized testing while having ordered output, you'd want to write a new RSpec formatter that supported ordered output. All things considered, formatters are pretty simple; they [implement a protocol defined by BaseFormatter](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_formatter.rb) and then output things as they see fit. You might look to the [default DocumentationFormatter code](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/documentation_formatter.rb) for inspiration.

Assuming you don't need this code to be widely reusable, you could even hard-code the order inside your formatter and skip the (fairly trivial, given it's Ruby) task of reading in a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

If you [provide the option `--order default`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order-new-in-rspec-core-2-8), `rspec` executes tests in the ordering imposed by the underlying filesystem: usually case-sensitive alphabetic on *NIX and case-insensitive alphabetic on Windows. So, you can control execution order by setting `--order default` in your `.rspec` file:

```
ash@dev ~/src/rspec-order $ cat .rspec
--color
--format doc
--order default
```

Then, name your spec files and directories with numeric prefixes that will sort in the order you want:

```
ash@dev ~/src/rspec-order $ ls -l spec/
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ash ash  96 Nov  4 16:04 001_first_spec.rb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ash ash 106 Nov  4 16:05 002_second_spec.rb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ash ash 734 Nov  4 16:03 spec_helper.rb
```

As a sidenote, one thing you are giving up by doing this is the ability to discover accidentally introduced ordering dependencies among your specs.